# regular expression to turn text into objective-c style string

Tags: regex, xcode

I'd like to see a regexp that turns a piece of text like:

```
{
   "text": "The quick \brown\ ",
   "more_text": "fox",
   "even_more": "jumps over the",
   "lazy": "dog"
}
```

into an objective-c compiler friendly string like:

```
NSString* mytext = 
@"{"
   "\"text\": \"The quick \\brown\\ \","
   "\"more_text\": \"fox\","
   "\"even_more\": \"jumps over the\","
   "\"lazy\": \"dog\""
"}";
```

In particular I need this regex to convert large JSON texts into an NSString to be fed as dummy data.

I plan to use this regexp in the find and replace function of Xcode where you can set it to use a regexp.

I don't have enough time now to brush up on my regexp magic spells and haven't found it elsewhere on the net.
I believe it would be useful for many objective c coders.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use @ only once - can you please clarify what you want on the objective-c side?

Comment: you're right, xcode tag should be more appropriate

Comment: Wrong about the XCode tag, this has nothing to do with XCode.

Comment: I think @tiguero means "that second string won't even compile, can you rewrite it in a fashion that it will"

Comment: Please check out my possible edit. Is this a practical version of what you want?

Comment: I edited the question, maybe it is clearer now. I set tags as objective-c or xcode because it would be useful only to people developing with objective-c and/or Xcode. C devs would probably also benefit because the constant string declaration differs only in the beginning @ sign.

Comment: @Flax: That is still not valid Objective-C code.

Comment: how is store your first text?

Answer (score -1):

$mytext=~s/\/\\/sg;   
substitutes \\ for \
$mytext=~s/"/\"/sg;  
substitutes \" for "
$mytext=~s/{(.*?)}/\@"{$1}";/sg;    
 substitutes @"{...}"; for {}

$mytext=~s/(\.*?),/"$1,"/g;
wraps each line that ends with a "," in quotes 


$mytext=~s/(\.*?\"\s}";)/"$1/g;  
adds quotes to last line